# Formula in Excel or Numbers to generate a series of numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, iwork-numbers

In my spreadsheet I have two numbers, `start_number` and `nr_iterations`. I'm looking for an formula that returns a series of numbers starting with `start_number - 1` and `nr_iterations` long (each following item with the value of one lower).

So like this:

```
(nr_iterations, start_number) => [my_number_serie]  
(0, 1) => []  
(1, 3) => [2]  
(2, 5) => [4, 3]  
(3, 7) => [6, 5, 4]  
(4, 9) => [8, 7, 6, 5]
```

Basically, start_number is also calculated, but probably is not too important:

```
start_number = 1 + nr_iterations*2
```

I'm actually interested in the `SUM` of this serie numbers, if that's of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following formulae in the cells indicated:-

```
[A1] =ROW(A1)-1
[B1] =2*A1+1
[C1] =B1*(B1-1)/2-A1*(A1+1)/2
```

Then copy `A1:C1` down as many rows as you need:

[image: Number Sequence]

Notes:-

- If you want column headers and you need your data to start at a different row, then change the offset in the first cell (eg to start from row 3, `A3` should be `=ROW(A3)-3`).
- The sum in column `C` is derived using the formula that the sum of the first **n** integers is **n*(n+1)/2**.
- I tested using LibreOffice, but Excel will be compatible.

Comment: That's it. And thanks for the explanation how to sum up the first n integer. It can actually be rewritten to `[C1] =(3*A1*A1+A1)/2` so you don't need `[B1]`, but your example is more clear.

Comment: I did realise that, but I left it as I did so as to show the logic of the calculation, as well as allowing for different upper bounds to the range.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it completely. If we break the formula from C1 into `[D1] = B1*(B1-1)/2` and `[E1] =A1*(A1+1)/2`, so we can redefine `[C1] = D1-E1`. In this, `E1` is `SUM(1..A1)`, but what is `D1`?

Comment: `D1` is `SUM(1..B1)-B1`, ie `SUM(1..(B1-1))`. Another way to see the formula is to substitute `B1-1` for **n** in **n*(n+1)/2**.